# How to retrieve a measure from SSAS tabular project using DAX script in SSMS?

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular, evaluate, ssas-2012

I have a tabular project with one fact table and few dimension tables.

The fact table Fact1 has a measure called `Number_of_Children`. How to retrieve that measure using `EVALUATE` statement is SSMS?

```
evaluate(values('Fact1 '[Number_of_Children]))
```

will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query must result in a table with at least a single column and row for the evaluation, as opposed to the single value returned by the measure.  The `EVALUATE` statement also doesn't need opening and closing parenthesis.  Use the `ROW` function to create a table consisting of the single row returned by the measure.

```
EVALUATE
ROW ( "Number of Childern", 'Fact1 '[Number_of_Children])
```

Comment: thanks for understandable explanation, along with the answer.

Comment: No problem.  If the answer I posted helped you feel free to mark it as accepted.  No obligation to do this, just makes things more clear for others who may see this post in the future.